# Left outer join in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

How to make LINQ query with left outer joins?

Comment: Just type *c# linq left outer join* in google and get at least [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx)

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov Now, now, Konsty - be nice to new commers. You should give him an appropriate link [like this one](http://bit.ly/WuihEC). Don't you agree?

Comment: @KonradViltersten 81 of reputation is fair enough to be already aware of the rules of this site. I guess I had given him all I was expected to.

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov I suspect you missed my point. Click the link and see what I meant. :)

Comment: Related post - [Linq join iquery, how to use defaultifempty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19293844/465053)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty.aspx) Method for left outer join.

You may see: [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx)

Consider the following example from MSDN,

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Left outer join query can be:

```
var query = from person in people
            join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
            from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 var query = (from t1 in Context.Table1
              join t2temp in Context.Table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id into tempJoin
              from t2 in tempJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select ...);
```