# ViewModel with three different tables, how to join the three tables by lambda into one result?

Tags: c#, join, lambda, asp-net-mvc-1

I have the following ViewModel:-

```
public class PostCommentReplyViewModel
{
     public List<POST> PostViewModel { get; set; }
     public List<COMMENT> CommentViewModel { get; set; }
     public List<REPLY> PostViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following Action in my Controller:-

```
EntityDataModel db = new EntityDataModel();
var vm = new PostCommentReplyViewModel();
vm.PostViewModel = db.POSTs.Join(db.COMMENTs, b => b.user_id, c => c.user_id, (b, c) => b).ToList();
return View(vm);
```

Now this action return result of the two join tables but when I try to join the three tables into one result I get no result, How can I join the three tables into one result?

[Linq Query Result to ViewModel](https://forums.asp.net/t/1922444.aspx?Linq%20Query%20Result%20to%20ViewModel)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, the most helpful solution I found to the problem is to create separate queries from ViewModel and then I attach them to one variable by the magic word Union and then I ask the ViewModel for the objects.

Here is the magic:

```
var resultOne = db.POSTs.Join(db.COMMENTs, b => b.user_id, c => c.user_id, (b, c) => b);
var resultTwo = db.POSTs.Join(db.REPLYs, b => b.user_id, c => c.user_id, (b, c) => b);
var resultUnion = resultOne.Union(resultTwo);
vm.PostViewModel = resultUnion.ToList();
return View(vm);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way, you only need to add 3rd join:

```
vm.PostViewModel = db.POSTs
            .Join(db.COMMENTs, b => b.user_id, c => c.user_id, (b, c) => b)
            .Join(db.REPLYs, b => b.user_id, c => c.user_id, (b, c) => b)
            .ToList();
```

The reason of no results might be that you don't have data in all 3 tables that can be INNER JOINed by the same key.

Comment: It could also be easily converted into not inner join: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19294132/2283405

Comment: The problem was that the key is not the same in the query, the thing is that I am now trying to get multiple results from the same table in different forms of queries..e.g. Create another query with two tables joined and return the results as well